# OpenAI API using python: Is there a way to create pandas dataframe using open ai's prompt?

Tags: python, openai-api

I was available to use openai's api using python and have a quick question regarding the Completion package.

I tried

```
response = openai.Completion.create(
  model="text-davinci-002",
  prompt="please create new pandas dataframe called 'df_openai' with three columns named 'column_1','column_2', and 'column_3, respectively with random data",
  temperature=0.3,
  max_tokens=60,
  top_p=1.0,
  frequency_penalty=0.8,
  presence_penalty=0.0
)
```

then, when I call response object, it returns JSON format data as below

```
<OpenAIObject text_completion id=cmpl-7026NSIzF9nKToCBiO41yeYT0FA4n at 0x1a9341e3240> JSON: {
  "choices": [
    {
      "finish_reason": "length",
      "index": 0,
      "logprobs": null,
      "text": "\n\ncolumn_1 column_2 column_3\n0.3745401188473625 15.494956001745766 0.9705927817606156\n0.15599452033620265 14.358679551569264 1.36208"
    }
  ],
  "created": 1680242435,
  "id": "cmpl-7026NSIzF9nKToCBiO41yeYT0FA4n",
  "model": "text-davinci-002",
  "object": "text_completion",
  "usage": {
    "completion_tokens": 60,
    "prompt_tokens": 37,
    "total_tokens": 97
  }
}
```

However, when I call df_openai dataframe in python, it shows that

```
name 'df_openai' is not defined
```

Is there a way to 'actually' create dataframe by using openai in python environment?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

If you are comfortable using a very powerful library called Langchain, then it's pretty much possible.

```
from langchain.agents import create_pandas_dataframe_agent
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('titanic.csv')
agent = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(OpenAI(temperature=0), df, verbose=True)

agent.run("how many rows are there?")
```

Please check [this](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/agents/toolkits/examples/pandas.html) link for documentation.

Hope it helps.